# Subscription canceled unexpectedly in service (from extended routed component)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a base component like this:

```ts
@Component({})
export class PageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title: string;

  constructor(
    /* other stuff */
    protected uiService: UIService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.uiService.set('title', this.title);
    this.uiService.set('something', false);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    /* cleanup */
  }
}
```

and several routed components that extend it, for example:

```
@ExtendedComponent({ templateUrl: './page-one.component.html' })
export class PageOneComponent extends PageComponent {
  title: string = 'Page One Title';
}

@ExtendedComponent({ templateUrl: './page-two.component.html' })
export class PageTwoComponent extends PageComponent {
  title: string = 'Page Two Title';

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    /* do stuff specific to PageTwoComponent */
    this.uiService.set('something', true);
  }
}
```

`@ExtendedComponent` decorator is this:

```
export function ExtendedComponent(annotation: any) {
  return (target: Function) => {
    const parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;

    const parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);
    const metadata = new Component({ ...parentAnnotations[0],  ...annotation});
    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [metadata], target);

    const parentParamTypes = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', parentTarget);
    const parentParameters = Reflect.getMetadata('parameters', parentTarget);
    Reflect.defineMetadata('design:paramtypes', parentParamTypes, target);
    Reflect.defineMetadata('parentParameters', parentParameters, target);
  };
}
```

The issue I'm having is with `UIService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class UIService {
  private buffer: any = {};
  private dispatcher: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.dispatcher
      .map(state => this.buffer = { ...this.buffer, ...state })
      .debounceTime(50)
      .do(() => { /* does something */})
      .subscribe();
  }

  set(key: string, value: any) {
    console.log(this.dispatcher.observers); // <-- [MapSubscriber] when working
                                            // <-- [] when not working
    this.dispatcher.next({ [key]: value });
  }
}
```

When I navigate between pages with other components (not shown here) everything works fine. But when I navigate from `PageOneComponent` to `PageTwoComponent` (both extend `PageComponent`), **dispatcher** subject in UIService is stops working (`console.log` in set method shows an empty array after a few calls).

I don't know why this is happening or what might be causing it. Any ideas?

Comment: you do not pass any functions to subscribe() method. So I guess subscriptions are removed by garbage collector

Comment: @Rem Think you're right, I moved `() => { /* does something */}` from `do()` to `subscribe()` and it seams it works.. Thanks! If you can add an answer I'll accept (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not pass any functions to subscribe() method. So subscriptions are removed by garbage collector